# Why all subdomains are directing to same service?

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, redirection, nginx, subdomain

I have 3 subdomains: `a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com, c.mydomain.com` configured by domain provider as following:

```
Name TTL Type  Value
a    1d  CNAME @
b    1d  CNAME @
c    1d  CNAME @
```

And the nginx configuration of the service, that should be on the subdomain a:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name a.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /nowhere;
  ...
  rewrite ^ https://a.mydomain.com$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name a.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off;
  ...
  # ssl staff and normal config
}
```

So the http://a.mydomain.com is forwarded to https://a.mydomain.com.
Other subdomains are not configured. But somehow https://b.mydomain.com and https://c.mydomain.com are redirected to https://a.mydomain.com and http://a.mydomain.com, https://b.mydomain.com are not redirected.

Why it looks like there are no server_name setting in nginx config? I would like to have many subdomains on my nginx server

Comment: Based on the configuration its because a.mydomain.com is the default rule.  To avoid the behavior you experienced define the rule for the other domains.

Comment: so the default rule - do the same redirect for all subdomains? But I did explicitly only `server { ... server_name a.mydomain.com; }`

Comment: Have you tried to create a rule for those other domains.  Your statement is also confusing, might want to read it again, and clarify the statement.

Comment: @static When nginx receives a request for a domain for which it has no configuration (such as `b.mydomain.com`), it uses the configuration for the first server block it finds: In this case "rewrite the domain to `https://a.mydomain.com`"; The end result is `http://b.mydomain.com` is rewritten to `https://a.mydomain.com`. Write up configuration for `b.mydomain.com` before asking about why it isn't working.

Comment: But the http://mydomain.com is not in the config and it opens the default nginx welcome-page. Why the b.mydomain.com cannot do the same (show the default nginx page)?