# Configure Nginx to reverse proxy docker containers to subdomains

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name https://domain.dev
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.dev.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://wiki;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name https://gitlab.domain.dev
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.dev.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://gitlab;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name https://wiki.domain.dev
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.dev.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://wiki;
    }
}
```

The below configuration will have the following undesired behavior given the following input.

www.domain.dev => http://wiki === good.

domain.dev => http://wiki === good.

**gitlab.domain.dev => http://wiki === wrong. expected http://gitlab;**

wiki.domain.dev => http://wiki === good.

Why is it that the above configuration always points to the wiki container even though it is configured to redirect to the gitlab container when entering in "gitlab.domain.dev" as the url?

I found [Why all subdomains are directing to same service?](https://superuser.com/questions/611408/why-all-subdomains-are-directing-to-same-service) but I think the intent of the poster was to have all the sub-domains go to the same service? Or maybe the poster switched stated intent to save some imaginary resource.Anyway, it's basically the opposite of my intent.

Comment: Your `server_name` directives are all wrong, so Nginx is using the first `server` block as default. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details, but remove the `https://` part from all the values.